# how to write a file to a particular folder in java?

Tags: java, file, directory, bufferedimage

I did this program which takes screenshots using the robot class and bufferedimage class. The .png file which contains the screenshots is getting saved to the folder where the .java file is present.I want the image files to be written in another folder called screenshot which i created. I tried renaming the files , also tried copying using inputstream and outputstream classes, but with the same result. How could I overcome this? I use windows 8 and java 1.8.0

```
package screenshot;

//Packages imported for the program

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

//Class logic written beside each statement

public class Screenshot 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {       

     try                                                                                    
     {                                                //Exception Handling
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy H-m'.png'");                   //Setting the date format 
        Date date=new Date();                                                             //Getting the current date and time
        String ref=df.format(date);                                                       //Formatting the current date in the SDF constructor's format
        //String dirname="M:\\Java\\bin\\screenshot\\";
        System.out.println(ref);                                                          //Testing whether the current date is getting displayed in the desired format
        Robot robot = new Robot();                                                        //Instanciating the Robot class       
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());          //Declaring a rectangle with size of the screen
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);                        //Capturing the screenshot and save it in Buffered image object
        //File dir = new File(dirname);
        //File filen = new File("M:\\Java\\bin\\screenshot\\temp.png");
        File filename = new File(ref);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png" , filename); //writing the image to a file called filename

     }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
       System.err.println(e);  //Exception message display
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: You commented out lines for changing the directory - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name is same as the name of the destination folder. Changing the package name or the folder name, every method listed is working fine

Answer (score 0):

to store file to the folder `screenshot`, change the variable

```
String ref=df.format(date);
```

to

```
String ref = "absolute_path_of_folder/" + df.format(date); // like "C:/screenshot/" + df.format(date);
```

it will save file to that folder.

Comment: change the file name and then try...i think its becoz of filename..try with temporary file name and test it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Note I use the two-argument constructor for `File` which takes a `File` representing the directory, and a name for a file inside that directory. I uncommented your lines describing which directory to save to, and used that directory.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy H-m'.png'");                   //Setting the date format 
    Date date=new Date();                                                             //Getting the current date and time
    String ref=df.format(date);                                                       //Formatting the current date in the SDF constructor's format
    String dirname="M:\\Java\\bin\\screenshot\\";
    System.out.println(ref);                                                          //Testing whether the current date is getting displayed in the desired format
    Robot robot = new Robot();                                                        //Instanciating the Robot class       
    Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());          //Declaring a rectangle with size of the screen
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);                        //Capturing the screenshot and save it in Buffered image object
    File dir = new File(dirname);
    File filen = new File("M:\\Java\\bin\\screenshot\\temp.png");
    File filename = new File(filen, ref);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png" , filename); //writing the image to a file called filename
```

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work , so I commented them.

Comment: If you will provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can actually run your code, then we can provide more help. But I don't have your `Robot` class or `ImageIO`... an MCVE and more details about what goes wrong would go a long way.